# More equations than unknowns for maxwell equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I had one curiosity regarding maxwell equations in 3-D

From the curl equations, you get 6 unknowns, with 6 equations. The divergence equations add 2 additional equations. When these are combined, we have 6 unknowns and 8 equations. I was curious if someone could give insight for why this is the case? More equations than unknowns makes me think that the solution is not unique.

Comment: Don't you mean "makes me think that there are no solutions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that the two equations involving divergences are redundant provided that they are satisfied at any given specific time (that is, with this last assumption the two equations follow from the other six). This was shown by Stratton in the 1940's.

Comment: Howdy, thanks for the response. When would these divergence equations not be satisfied?

Comment: Well, from the mathematical point of view it is only a matter of computing the divergences and check whether the two laws are satisfied at a given point, but say for example Gauss' law says that the electrical flow through a closed surface is equal to the total charge inside.

Comment: Numerically, when you are dealing with these guys, there is always error. Therefore I dont believe you could ever satisfy the divergence equations. Can you just be safe with solving the curl equations?

Comment: :) I believe that it is basically the same .

Comment: Thank you for the help. Very appreciated.